# renormalization by differentiation how does it work?

Tags: regularization

i mean let be the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{p^{3}}{(p^{2}+m^{2})^{2}} $$

logartihmic divergence but if a apply differentiation with respect to $ m^{2} $ i get

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-2p^{3}}{(p^{2}+m^{2})^{3}}=I(m) $$ wich is convergent so

is the real integral then of the form $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{p^{3}}{(p^{2}+m^{2})^{2}}= D^{-1}I(m)+C_{m}  $$

and if so how i get the constant $ C_{m} $

Comment: It is possible that you can find the solution in section 5.5.4 of Le Bellac?